# random number comparison not matching absolute value correctly

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My program doesn't function correctly, it says I'm 10 away when i'm only 3 away.

```
      var ranNum = 48
      var numbered = 45

      if (ranNum === numbered){
        alert("match");
      }else if ((Math.abs(numbered - ranNum)) < 10){
        alert("your ten away");
      }else if ((Math.abs(numbered - ranNum)) < 5){
        alert("your five away");
      }
```

The output says it's 10 away when it's not.

Comment: Isn't -3 less than 10?

Comment: its calculating the absolute value which makes it a positive nubmer

Comment: You are right, but still 3 is less than 10. That's why it alerts "your ten away".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 3 is less than 10 so that is valid. The first if/else condition that matches will win.
You should put your < 5 check first...or improve your first check to ensure the number is >5 and <10 if that is your desired outcome.